# Integrate Single Sign On using Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security and I would like to use another site as one of my authentication providers.  I have a basic form based login on my site.  I want to have a link on my site  that takes the user to an external site where they will login and that external site will then post a xml response back to me with data that I can verify to see if there was a successful login. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

1. How do you integrate that flow into Spring Security?
2. Once I get the response back, how would I auto log user on?

example using the guidance below:

filter (not shown my data is coming from xml off the request):

```
public class XMLAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter{

    public XMLAuthenticationFilter() {
        super("/xml_security_check");
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException,
            IOException, ServletException {

            GrantedAuthority[] grantedAuthorities = new GrantedAuthority[] { new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_USER")};
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("userid", "pwd", grantedAuthorities);
            request.getSession();
            token.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(request));
            Authentication authenticatedUser = super.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(token);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticatedUser);
            request.getSession().setAttribute(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY, SecurityContextHolder.getContext());
            return authenticatedUser;

}
```

}

Auth Provider:

```
public class XMLAuthenticationProvider extends AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider{
    private UserManager userManager;
    @Override
    protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails user, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException {

    }

    @Override
    protected UserDetails retrieveUser(String userName, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException {
        UserDetails user = userManager.getUser(userName); 
        if(user == null){
            Users newDCUser = new Users();
            newDCUser.setUserId(userName);
            newDCUser.setRawPassword((String) token.getCredentials());
            newDCUser.setFailedLoginAttempts(0);
            newDCUser.setBeginEffectiveDate(new Date());
            newDCUser.setEndEffectiveDate(getEffectiveDate());
            userManager.saveUser(newDCUser);
        }
        return userManager.loadUserByUsername(userName);
    }

    private Date getEffectiveDate(){
         Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
         calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, 10);
         return calendar.getTime();
    }

    public UserManager getUserManager() {
        return userManager;
    }

    public void setUserManager(UserManager userManager) {
        this.userManager = userManager;
    }
}
```

bean config:

```
<bean id="xmlAuthenticationFilter" class="com.dc.api.service.impl.XMLAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="am" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="xmlAuthenticationProvider" class="com.dc.api.service.impl.XMLAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="userManager" ref="userManager"/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Does the external site use Spring Security and is it in the same domain?

Comment: Hi ericacm, thanks for the response.  No to both questions.  I have to redirect to it and then they're doing a POST back to me with an xml that I have to parse and use its attributes to tell if the user successfully authenticated. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it SAML or is it some custom XML that is unique to the site?

Comment: custom xml unique to the site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The general approach is:

1) Subclass AbstractAuthenticationToken for your XML logins, let's call it XMLAuthenticationToken.

2) Subclass AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter and add it to the filter chain after UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.  It should create a XMLAuthenticationToken based on the data in the XML.   You can use UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter as an example for the general structure of the filter (that's most likely the filter that you are currently using for your regular Spring Security logins).

```
<http>
  <custom-filter after="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="xmlAuthenticationFilter"/>
</http>
```

The filter should set a filterProcessesUrl that is different from the UsernamePasswordFilter.  This is the URL the external system will post the XML to.  For example:

```
public XmlAuthenticationFilter() {
    super("/xml_security_check");
}
```

3) Subclass AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.  Have it look up the user from the UserDetailsService based on the info in the token, and then authenticate it.   Use DaoAuthenticationProvider as an example.   You will need to register the new provider with the AuthenticationManager.

```
<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider user-service-ref='myUserDetailsService'/>
  <authentication-provider ref="xmlAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>
```

You might be able to get away with reusing UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken (for #1, it has a nice "details" extension mechanism) and DaoAuthenticationProvider (or subclassing it) for #3.

Comment: thanks, I'll give it a shot tonight.  appreciate the assistance.

Comment: ericacm how do I configure my application to use this form of authentication vs the form based method.  I have a link for both inside the app but how does Spring do the mapping?

Comment: By adding the new filter to the chain and adding the new provider to the AuthenticationManager.  I added examples of how to do this to #2 and #3.

Comment: This will support both the existing form login and the XML login.  To support just the XML login change "after" to "position" in the custom-filter tag and remove the first authentication-provider.

Comment: how will I tell my app to use the second authentication provider and run the second filter?  In my case the user will bypass the form based login and go straight to the xml based auth from a link inside my application.  I'll keep readying spring security 3 book and see if I can get it.  I added some of my existing config above...thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, forgot one thing.   You set a filterProcessesUrl on your new filter to tell that filter to only apply to a certain path, the path that the external system POSTs the XML to which will be different from the URL that the UsernamePasswordFilter uses (see my addition to #2).

Comment: Hey ericacm.  I finally got to try this out and thus far im struggling a bit. Since I'm using the  <remember-me user-service-ref="userManager" key="key value"/> do I need to create a RememberMeAuthenticationToken and then store it in the context at the end?

Comment: No, spring security will handle that for you since you have the <remember-me> element.

Comment: I updated my post above with my new config, maybe you can take a look and help.  I get a the exception I copied above when I include these new components. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: where is the xmlAuthenticationFilter bean defined?

Comment: I have <bean id="xmlAuthenticationFilter" class="com.dc.api.service.impl.XMLAuthenticationFilter"/> in the WEB-INF/dc-context-api.xml file.  I have two spring security files one for beans one for security.

Comment: what version of spring security are you using

Comment: spring-security-core-3.1.0.M1.jar

Comment: is it possible to drop down to 3.0.5?   3.1 is not released for general use and may have bugs.

Comment: so after a few tries I finally go it mostly functioning thanks to your guidance. I do have one last question.  Once I verify the incoming xml's signature the user is guaranteed to be logged in. If they don't exist then I must add them and I have that working as well.  The one place I run into issues is that I need to take more info than the userid and password and save that (firstname, lastname..etc).  The retrieveUser method only takes a username and not a UserDetails.  Where/how could I set all my user info before inserting them?  I updated my code above, thanks again!

Comment: is that user info in the xml that is sent?

Comment: also, did you create your own Authentication class or did you reuse UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken?

Comment: also, I should be able to just pull the xml off the request in the XMLAuthenticationFilter's attemptAuthentication method right?

Comment: Yes, and add the info to the details of the UsernamePasswordAuthToken.  Then you can either validate the signature and add the user in the filter or later in the provider.

Comment: well how do you do that if I'm already setting the token's details method with the a new WebAuthenticationDetails(request) object?request.getSession();
         token.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(request));

Comment: subclass WebAuthenticationDetails and add your stuff.

Comment: Hi Ericacm, It seems that when I implemented this approach my passwords no longer matter in the form based login.  I can enter any password for a user and I wont get a BadCredentialsException and the user will be loaded.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Ericacm, I have posted my query below. your help would be appreciated.