# Single Sign-On on Spring Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm working on a web application under Tomcat on a Linux server and all clients are under a windows domain. I need to get the user account from the request to assign it the right role on my application. So to summarize I just need to retrieve the user account becasue the authentication is not required.

What could be the more easy framework or solution to do that? Jaas could be the solution?

Could you help me, please?

thanks,
Andrea

Comment: I'm interested to know how you are going to get the Windows account from the request.

Comment: When I'll complete this task I'll give you an update.

Comment: Any success, or didn't you complete the task?

Comment: No, not for the moment..... :(

Comment: Are you referring to windows integrated authentication? I.e. you want to use the existing windows authentication session?

Comment: Yeah! Exactly that one

Answer (score 8):

Have you checked out Spring-Security?

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/

Spring Security supports Single Sign On options using Kerberos, JNDI/LDAP, Active Directory, OAuth, OpenID, etc.

[Integrate Single Sign On using Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365054/integrate-single-sign-on-using-spring-security)

Answer (score 2):

Try the [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/) project, former JSecurity.