# Is there an example of integrating a Remote SSO to a web application with Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, single-sign-on

I am trying to setup my application using Spring Security. I haven't used spring security before, and I've read the basic architecture site here: https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture/. In my use case, I have a remote SSO application that my company uses which sits on a different domain. Each of the pages on the application is protected (minus logout), and for each unauthenticated request, the page should redirect to the remote SSO application's login page, where the user will enter their credentials and authenticate. The SSO application will redirect the user back to the requested page after they successfully log in. My application will then use Spring Security to validate the SSO response, populate user details, and create the proper authorization. Once all of that is done, the user will have access to the page(s).

After reading this: [Integrate Single Sign On using Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365054/integrate-single-sign-on-using-spring-security), I think I understand what I have to do for most of it. However, I'm still unclear as to how to get Spring Security to redirect the application to the SSO application if the request is unauthenticated.

Thanks,

JC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to use a pre-authentication scenario. They are described in detail here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/preauth.html.

In order to get the application to redirect, you just enter the remote URL in the form-login property.